# Please identify this broken LEGO Technic piece

Tags: technic, part-identification

This piece is from LEGO Technic 8070 Super Car. Can anyone please identify its name as it's broken and I need to get a new one.

[image: Broken Technic Piece]

Comment: since you started probably knowing the set number, a search for ["lego 8070 part list"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=lego+8070+part+list") will take you to the [brickset inventory](http://brickset.com/inventories/8070-1) very easily.

Comment: The very first step you can do if you knwo the set number is go through [the LEGO customer service](https://service.lego.com/fr-be/replacementparts#WhatProduct) where you can type the set number and see its inventory. If your part is there and is in green, you can order it directly from LEGO (usually for free if the part is broken). In this case it wouldn't have helped as the part in question is not currently in production (appears in red), but at least it helps you identify the part as well.

Answer (score 13):

Sure looks like one of these: [Technic, Steering Gear with 4 Ball Joints, Complete Assembly with Black Base](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=x873c01)

It comes in a [handful of sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x873c01&in=S)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. You were right! Found the piece on ebay.

Comment: I've moved the text above the image to make it easier to see ;)